# php regular expression concatenation unwanted backslashes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression in php. I tested it here https://regex101.com/ and it works fine, but that was before I knew I'd have to implement it in php and it adds backslashes where not needed.

Here's my code:

```
$datePattern        = "\[((19|20)\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\]";
$tag                = "[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*";
$regroupmentPattern = "\[($tag)?\]";
$taglistPattern     = "\[((?:$tag)?(?:;(?:$tag))*)\]";
$countryPattern     = "\[([a-z]{2})\]";
$freePattern        = "\[([^\[\]]*)\]";
$extensionPattern   = "\.(jpg|png)";
$repetitionPattern  = "(?:\(\d+\))?";

$fullPattern        = "/^$datePattern$regroupmentPattern$taglistPattern$countryPattern$freePattern$freePattern$extensionPattern$repetitionPattern$/";
```

Here is what I want :

```
^\[((19|20)\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\]\[([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?\]\[((?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?(?:;(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*))*)\]\[([a-z]{2})\]\[([^\[\]]*)\]\[([^\[\]]*)\](?:\(\d+\))?\.(jpg|png)$
```

And here's what I get :

```
"\"\\/^\\\\[((19|20)\\\\d\\\\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\\\]\\\\[([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?\\\\]\\\\[((?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?(?:;(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*))*)\\\\]\\\\[([a-z]{2})\\\\]\\\\[([^\\\\[\\\\]]*)\\\\]\\\\[([^\\\\[\\\\]]*)\\\\]\\\\.(jpg|png)(?:\\\\(\\\\d+\\\\))?$\\/\""
```

I assume there must be some sort of escape function, I tried preg_quote but it added yet even more backslashes.

Btw here's my full code:

```
<?php
  class Gallery {
    // Name of the gallery, used to build folder path
    private $name;

    function __construct($name) {
      $this->name = $name;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the list of file names in a gallery folder,
     * or false if the folder doesn't exist
     */
      public function getFileNames() {
        $path = "../../gallery/$this->name";
        if (is_dir($path)) {
          $allFileNamesArray = scandir($path, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING);
          $filteredFileNamesArray = array();

          // Building regular expression
          $datePattern        = "\[((19|20)\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\]";
          $tag                = "[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*";
          $regroupmentPattern = "\[($tag)?\]";
          $taglistPattern     = "\[((?:$tag)?(?:;(?:$tag))*)\]";
          $countryPattern     = "\[([a-z]{2})\]";
          $freePattern        = "\[([^\[\]]*)\]";
          $extensionPattern   = "\.(jpg|png)";
          $repetitionPattern  = "(?:\(\d+\))?";

          $fullPattern        = "/^$datePattern$regroupmentPattern$taglistPattern$countryPattern$freePattern$freePattern$extensionPattern$repetitionPattern$/";

          foreach ($allFileNamesArray as $fileName) {
            $matches = array();
            if (preg_match($fullPattern, $fileName, $matches, PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL)) {
              $filteredFileNamesArray[] = $fileName;
            }
            var_dump($matches);
          }

          return json_encode($fullPattern);
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
  }
?>
```

(Here I returned fullPattern istead of filteredFileNamesArray for debugging purpose)

Comment: You [get](https://3v4l.org/2lSaW) `/^\[((19|20)\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\]\[([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?\]\[((?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?(?:;(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*))*)\]\[([a-z]{2})\]\[([^\[\]]*)\]\[([^\[\]]*)\]\.(jpg|png)(?:\(\d+\))?$/` Why do you return `return json_encode($fullPattern)`? Try `return $fullPattern;` to see the actual regex.

Comment: Yeah sorry, then it returns: "/^\\[((19|20)\\d\\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\]\\[([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?\\]\\[((?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?(?:;(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*))*)\\]\\[([a-z]{2})\\]\\[([^\\[\\]]*)\\]\\[([^\\[\\]]*)\\]\\.(jpg|png)(?:\\(\\d+\\))?$/"

Comment: It still doesn't match my strings that do pass on https://regex101.com/

Comment: So, you swapped `$repetitionPattern` and `$extensionPattern`. Use `"/^$datePattern$regroupmentPattern$taglistPattern$countryPattern$freePattern$freePattern$repetitionPattern$extensionPattern$/"`

Comment: Oh damn thanks you and thanks for the link to the online php editor it's very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped `$repetitionPattern` and `$extensionPattern`.

Use

```
$fullPattern = "/^$datePattern$regroupmentPattern$taglistPattern$countryPattern$freePattern$freePattern$repetitionPattern$extensionPattern$/";
```

It will result in

`^\[((19|20)\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\]\[([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?\]\[((?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)?(?:;(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*))*)\]\[([a-z]{2})\]\[([^\[\]]*)\]\[([^\[\]]*)\](?:\(\d+\))?\.(jpg|png)$` pattern.

See the [regex demo  online](https://regex101.com/r/PTYKe8/1).